# Python pull parsers

Tags: php, python, xml

I'm looking for a fast Python pull parser (maybe some equivalent of PHP's XMLReader?) - is there something like this in Python? It's really a key feature that it would be a pull parser, because I'm gonna process really big xml files...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP's XMLReader is nothing but a SAX parser ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML ).

Python supports SAX parsing. There are many tutorials available, like this one: 
http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/XML/Parsing-XML-with-SAX-and-Python/

Answer (score 1):

How about the built-in ones python has?

http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html ("full DOM implementation")

and http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html ("lightweight DOM implementation")

source: http://developer.yahoo.com/python/python-xml.html

Comment: But are those pull parsers? I don't want (and don't need) to build a full DOM tree for my xml documents.